# How do I apply CSS Transition to my responsive menu?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-transitions

I created a small responsive menu

http://jsfiddle.net/8gApb/1/

It works exactly like I want it too.

However, I would like the menu to actually transition out instead of just happening immediately.

Ive tried adding

```
    #nav:target > ul
    {
        display: block;
        transition: display 2s linear;

    }
```

and that didnt work. I also tried

```
    #nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type,
    #nav:target > a:last-of-type
    {
        display: inline-block;
        transition: display 2s linear;
    }
```

And once again I was unsuccessful.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: You cannot transition the `display` property. You would need to set the `opacity` to 0 and transition the `opacity` value

Comment: Could you perhaps edit my fiddle to show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/8gApb/2/

changed the display property to opacity and set it to 0

```
#nav > ul {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And then added transition to that too:

`transition: opacity 1s linear;`

And for the target:

```
#nav:target > ul {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: awesome thank you! Any suggestions for where I can study up on CSS transitions?

Comment: CSS Tricks is always good. [Check this article out](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)